# GUI-based x86 assembly editor

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, reassembly

Is there a tool that disassembles x86 executables, presents it in a GUI where you can edit the assembly commands, and reassembles it when you want to save/patch the exe?

All it would need is a tool that disassembles and reassembles x86 executables into a kind of text format .. like what `ildump` does with .NET.

Comment: Looking thru http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:PE_Executable_Editors

Comment: Explorer Suite claims to have "PE Rebuilding" is this what I'm after? disassemble > edit > reassemble?

Comment: LordPE? Hiew? http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Hiew

Comment: Codename Aslan? http://www.piotrbania.com/all/4514N/

Answer (score 3):

Use [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) with [pe_write.idc](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/download_file/57).

There's a full walk-through here: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/applied-cracking-byte-patching-ida-pro/

Answer (score 2):

Use IDA Pro. This is exactly the tool you're asking for. For patching the binary, use the options under the menu Edit -> Patch.

Comment: How do you edit an opcode with IDA? I can't find any way of doing that.

Comment: Either in the hex viewer or via Edit -> Patch program -> Change byte/word or Assemble. My guess is that you're using "an old version" of IDA. In this case, you need to modify $IDA_DIR/cfg/idagui.cfg uncomenting the line that refers to the patch menu.

Answer (score 1):

Althought the 'GUI' is console based, I always used HIEW.

Answer (score 1):

[Ollydbg](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ollydbg%20%22patch%22) is a free tool - it's more of a debugger than a disassembler.